# Derivation of higher order bessel function in terms of lower order functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, power-series

I am really stuck trying to prove this..

((x^-p)Jp(x))’ = -(x^-p)Jp+1(x)          ---(1)

Can someone please help how to actually prove this step by step, because whichever notes i see, they prove for ((x^p)Jp(x))’ = (x^p)Jp-1(x), and say similarly the other one can be proved, i did try to prove but my order of x in equation 1 doesn't seem to match.